# Can't save configration in router(gns3 )

Tags: cisco, router, linux, gns3

I have installed gns3 v2.1.9 with gns3 vm(oracle v5.2.18) in my Ubuntu 64bit v18.04.

I have installed 2 routers 3725 and 3745 in gns3 vm.

But if i try to save my config with

```
   copy running-config startup-config.
```

Then i am getting below errors.

```
Dynamips hypervisor process has stopped, return code: -11
'Ghost': generic_nvram_extract_config: Unknown error -61605
Could not send Dynamips command 'vm set_ghost_status "R1" 2' to 
0.0.0.0:51720: Connection lost, process running: False
```

PS :Router does not starts after error.i have to replace it with new router.Moreover GNS3 vm and Gns3 is in same Network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save configuration using command `write memory` and delete using `write erase`